# Why is my jQuery-ui script not working on wordpress? (it loads succesfully with no errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

the Jquery script is here (using jQuery-ui):

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready( function(slider) {

$("#amount").val("How many cigarettes do you smoke a day?");
$("#amountb").val("How much do you pay for a 10 pack of cigarettes?");


$( function() {

    var t = {

        0: "0",
        10: "5",
        20: "10",
        30: "15",
        40: "20",
        50: "25",
        60: "30",
        70: "35",
        80: "40",
        90: "45",
        100: "50",

    }

    var d = {

        0: "0",
        0.5:"0.5",
        1:"1.00",
        1.5:"1.5",
        2: "2.00",
        2.5: "2.50",
        3: "3.00",
        3.5: "3.50",
        4: "4.00",
        4.5: "4.50",
        5: "5.00",
        5.5: "5.50",
        6: "6.00",
        6.5: "6.50",
        7: "7.00",
        7.5: "7.50",
    }


    $("#slider").slider({

        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 10,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var a=$("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
         update();
        }
    });


    $("#sliderb").slider({
        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 7.5,
        step: 0.5,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#priceb").val(d[ui.value]);
             update();
        }
    });



}
);


});

function update()
{
    var a=document.getElementById('price').value;
    var b=document.getElementById('priceb').value;
    var total=((parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b))*365)/10;
    document.getElementById('total').value=""+total;

    var c=document.getElementById('total').value;

    var viva=parseFloat(c)-(((parseFloat(a)/10)*30)*12);
    document.getElementById('viva').value=""+viva;
}
```

And my html is here: (note the divs with ID's slider & sliderb relating to above script)

```
<div class="wrappernew">
        <div class="colThree" style="margin: 0px 0 20px 0px; ">
    <div id="contenta">
                <form method="post" name="quoteme" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="quoteme">
                        <div id="slider"> </div>
                        <label for="amount"> </label>
                        <input name="one" style="width: 400px;" type="text" id="amount" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
                        <label for="price"> </label>
                        <input name="onea" type="text" id="price" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
                        <div id="sliderb"> </div>
                        <label for="amountb"> </label>
                        <input name="two" style="width: 400px;"  type="text" id="amountb" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
                        <label for="priceb"> </label>
                        <input name="twoa" type="text" id="priceb" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
                        <p class="pricepara"> You spend £
                    <label for="total" id="totalprice" style=""> </label>
                    <input name="totalprice" type="text" id="total" disabled="disabled" style="" />
                    on cigarettes each year. </p>
                        <p class="pricepara"> By switching to Viva you could save £
                    <label for="viva" id="totalprice" style=""> </label>
                    <input name="totalprice" type="text" id="viva" disabled="disabled" style="" />
                    each year. </p>
                    </div>
        </form>
            </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The website in question is http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/ and what should be the slider is on the home page however the script just isn't making an impression on the HTML.

I'm not a programmer but I thought I would give it a go at doing it myself, I got everything working locally but its just gone to pieces when I've added it to wordpress.

I've loaded all the same scripts on wordpress as I have locally, however I cant help but feel that I am missing something on the page that tells the script to run?

Any and all help will be appreciated.

After replacing $ as per instruction this is the script:

```
// JavaScript Document

Jquery(document).ready( function(slider) {

Jquery("#amount").val("How many cigarettes do you smoke a day?");
Jquery("#amountb").val("How much do you pay for a 10 pack of cigarettes?");


Jquery( function() {

    var t = {

        0: "0",
        10: "5",
        20: "10",
        30: "15",
        40: "20",
        50: "25",
        60: "30",
        70: "35",
        80: "40",
        90: "45",
        100: "50",

    }

    var d = {

        0: "0",
        0.5:"0.5",
        1:"1.00",
        1.5:"1.5",
        2: "2.00",
        2.5: "2.50",
        3: "3.00",
        3.5: "3.50",
        4: "4.00",
        4.5: "4.50",
        5: "5.00",
        5.5: "5.50",
        6: "6.00",
        6.5: "6.50",
        7: "7.00",
        7.5: "7.50",
    }


    Jquery("#slider").slider({

        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 10,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var a=Jquery("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
         update();
        }
    });


    Jquery("#sliderb").slider({
        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 7.5,
        step: 0.5,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            Jquery("#priceb").val(d[ui.value]);
             update();
        }
    });



}
);


});

function update()
{
    var a=document.getElementById('price').value;
    var b=document.getElementById('priceb').value;
    var total=((parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b))*365)/10;
    document.getElementById('total').value=""+total;

    var c=document.getElementById('total').value;

    var viva=parseFloat(c)-(((parseFloat(a)/10)*30)*12);
    document.getElementById('viva').value=""+viva;
}
```

I have just added the above script as recommended to the website, but it is still not making an impression on the html, on my local version the script replaces the divs 'slider' and 'sliderb' with an actual slider.

I am not sure if it is of any help but I have zipped the file here: http://vivaelectroniccigarette.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/js/price_estimator-1.zip the file index.html is how it looks locally and what I get on the site can be seen at: vivaelectroniccigarette.com

Here is my the head and the order I am loading the files, is there a problem with this?

```
<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<title><?php woo_title(''); ?></title>
<?php woo_meta(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />



<?php
wp_head();
woo_head();
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/js/jquery-ui.css">
<script src='http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>
</script>
<script src="http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/js/myscript.js">
</script>
<script src="http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/js/jquery-ui.js">
</script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, you can call its function with `jQuery` instead of `$`  due to the jQuery noConflict Wrappers.

[Please look at this link for more info.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: So in the script do I replace all the $ with Jquery?

Sorry if this is a basic question, Its my first attempt at writing Jquery!

Comment: no problem, yes you definitely should replace every `$` with `Jquery` ;) I just rechecked your entire code, you can safely do `replace all` with your favorite text editor, to replace `$` with `Jquery`.

Comment: I edited the original question and added the script above with the correction you have recommended, is this what you meant?

Comment: I've just added this to the website, but it is still not making an impression on the html, on my local version the script replaces the divs 'slider' and 'sliderb' with an actual slider.

not sure if it is of any help but I have zipped the file here: 

http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/js/price_estimator-1.zip 

the index.html is how it should look and what I get on the site can be seen at: http://www.vivaelectroniccigarette.com/

Comment: Wordpress use of jQuery with no-conflict mode has populated many sites like this with questions. I suggest that until you figure out what it's all about, you deregister Wordpress' jQuery and use the jQuery on Google's CDN http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/

Comment: What would this do harry? Sorry if you feel like you're talking to an idiot, I'm just a bit out of my depth with this!

Comment: Sorry Chris, I don't see why it doesn't work, it means that there's another error, but the `Jquery` thing instead of the `$` was definitely the good thing to do.

Comment: yes Indeed, sorry, please try with `jQuery` instead of `Jquery`

Comment: Have done that sorry, I can now see that the script has an affect on the website, however the problem now seems to be that jquery-ui.js is not working. I tested this on my local version and when I remove jquery-ui.js it shows the same as the website is now showing.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress calls `jQuery.noConflict ()` By default situation , by default jQuery uses $ as a shortcut for jQuery < so you must Replace $ with jQuery word .... see [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: I added the script above with the correction you have recommended, is this what you meant?

Comment: yes off-course , just replace $ with jQuery , and be aware that jQuery  differs from jquery , and always remember that  Javascript is case sensitive language :)